# Setting the focus on a particular element from a list

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

I have a form which is used both - for editing and creating a new element. I have a `Combobox` with a `DropDownList` which is filled with a data from another table and no matter if the user is in for creating a new element I want be able to show him all the elements in the `DropDownList` but when he is for editing I want to set the focus to the same element as it was in the view page.

I these are the code parts that I use for this:

check if the user want to create a new element:

```
 if (!LoadEntityId.HasValue)
            {
                entity = new Material();
```

Load the entity if the user is editing such:

```
entity = materialService.Find(LoadEntityId.Value);
```

Load just the value of the loaded entity (the part I want to customize as explained) :

```
cboTypeOfMaterial.Text = entity.MaterialTypeName;
```

where `cboTypeOfMaterial` is the `ComboBox` name in the edit form.

Comment: Focus of what on what?

Comment: On the previously chosen element if the user is editing an existing form with set value instead of creating a new one. However it seems that giving the focus is by default...